# RCurl postForm Issue

Tags: r, forms, rcurl

I am trying to write a post request to [this site](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cansim/a26?lang=eng&retrLang=eng&id=2820001&&pattern=&stByVal=1&p1=1&p2=31&tabMode=dataTable&csid=) using RCurl's `postForm` function in R.

Using Chrome's developer tool, I have identified that the attribute I want to manipulate has the name `MBR['GEOGRAPHY']`.

However when I enter that in my `postForm` request as such:

```
postForm(url, MBR['GEOGRAPHY'] = 1,  style = "post")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "postForm(url, MBR['GEOGRAPHY'] ="
```

I have successfully used this function with other forms that have names that do not have the [''], so I am assuming this is the problem, but I am not sure how to work around it.

Comment: Your link gives: "invalid cansim table ID."

Comment: Sorry here is the table I am trying to manipulate with the postForm function. http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cansim/a26?lang=eng&retrLang=eng&id=2820001&&pattern=&stByVal=1&p1=1&p2=31&tabMode=dataTable&csid=

Answer (score 0):

The issues are with the square brackets (normally used for indexing). I get some text returned by doing:

```
postForm(url, "MBR['GEOGRAPHY']"=1,  style = "post")
```

whether that is the correct query or not; difficult to tell since the pages says: "invalid cansim table ID".

EDIT:

If you start with a more basic URL:

```
http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cansim/a26?id=2820001
```

You can successfully apply parameters like `lang`:

```
postForm(url, lang = "fra", style = "post")
```

which returns the page in French. It turns out I can change the geography manually by appending it to the URL: `&MBR%5B%27GEOGRAPHY%27%5D=2`, but I'm not able to pass that through RCurl. However, you can build the URL manually, then pass it, which works:

```
postForm(paste(url, "&MBR%5B%27GEOGRAPHY%27%5D=2", sep=""), style = "post")
```

Comment: I will try this out tonight, but makes sense. What if I wanted to select multiple geographies since there are technically 11 values associated with "&MBR%5B%27GEOGRAPHY%27%5D". Any idea how I would manipulate the URL in situation like this?

Comment: Not sure. If you have more questions about the encoding formats, I would suggest posting a new more specific question.